# When to use user defined functions in a SQL Server data warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I am working on creating a DWH where I am loading the data in Staging DB and before loading them into final DB I apply all the udfs that I have created on the data.

- Source DB   : Oracle
- Dest DB     : SQL Server
- ETL Process : SSIS packages

I was not processing anything on staging to have a quick load.

Question:  is it quicker to apply any udfs when the data is in staging itself or should it be done when loading the data to final DB.

Below `facility_cd` is a `float` value and I am passing it to a function `emr_get_code_Description` to get the corresponding description. The table where it's getting the description from is in the final DB. `udf_replace_special_char` is a simple function which is replacing a few special characters with NULL.

```
LTRIM(RTRIM([Dest_DWH].[dbo].udf_replace_special_char([Dest_DWH].[dbo].[emr_get_code_Description](Stg_ap.Facility_cd))))
```

In general what should be a better practice? Should I be updating this in staging and then load the data after all conversions to Final DB.

Function definitions :

Function 1 :

```
USE [PROD_DWH]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER function [dbo].[emr_get_code_Description](@cv int)  
returns varchar(80)  
as begin   

-- Returns the code value display 
    declare @ret varchar(80)  
    select @ret = cv.DESCRIPTION
        from PROD_DWH.DBO.table cv   
        where cv.code_value = @cv   
            and cv.active_ind = 1  

    return isnull(@ret, 0)

end;
```

Function 2 :

```
USE [PROD_DWH]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER function [dbo].[udf_replace_special_char](@var varchar(1000))  
returns varchar(1000)  
as begin   
-- Returns the code value display 
    declare @return_var varchar(1000)  
    set @return_var = @var
    set @return_var = replace(@return_var,CHAR(13),'')
    set @return_var = replace(@return_var,CHAR(10),'')
    set @return_var = replace(@return_var,CHAR(09),'')
    set @return_var = replace(@return_var,CHAR(34),CHAR(39))

    return isnull(@return_var, 0)

end;
```

Comment: I’d guess from staging to final but really this is all depending on a lot of variables and I’d just test both to figure out your answer.

Comment: Best practice is to not use UDF's at all because they have the potential to introduce performance issues. I would also say that it's best practice to prepare the data completely beforehand in staging, then ensure the load from staging to dw is as quick as possible to reduce reporting impact. i.e. use partition switching and or snapshot isolation with transactions

Comment: I totally agree with you Nick. It was taking one hour after introducing one function and now after adding the second one its taking 2.5 hrs.I can remove the udf_replace_special_char by replace statement. but the other function is actually contains a select statement. I have added the function definitions in the initial question.

Comment: The function emr_get_code_Description is being used almost 20 times in a single table load. I read somewhere that table valued functions give better performance but in this case it is impossible to use them as I need to use the function many times in a stored procedure. Any suggestion on how I can replace the functions with something else would be great. @Hadi

Comment: @Doodle as i mentioned in my answer, you can replace it with a Join in your main query

Comment: Thanks Hadi. I have tried the joins before and its like joining the same table 20 times to get the values.Which wasn't that efficient as well. So I was searching for other alternatives.

Comment: "its like joining the same table 20 times" why is that problem? That's pretty normal. The staging component of a DW by necessity does some repetitive things. Repetitive code is sometime the price you pay for performance.

Comment: Its a problem because its taking long as well!!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First of all, as @Nick.McDermaid mentioned in the comments: Best practice is to avoid using User defined functions. There are many links containing information about the functions effects on query performance.*

- [Removing Function Calls for Better Performance in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2727/removing-function-calls-for-better-performance-in-sql-server/)
- [Performance Considerations of User-Defined Functions in SQL Server 2012](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/performance-considerations-of-user-defined-functions-in-sql-server-2012)
- [Are SQL Server Functions Dragging Your Query Down?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/sql-server-functions-dragging-query/)
- [T-SQL Best Practices - Don't Use Scalar Value Functions in Column List or WHERE Clauses](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3845381/T-SQL-Best-Practices-150-Don146t-Use-Scalar-Value-Functions-in-Column-List-or-WHERE-Clauses.htm)

---

There is not ideal answer for these question, it is related to the case you are working with, but i can give some tips that you can take into consideration:

- First, if you are using SSIS to import data into Staging Table, try replacing user defined function with the SSIS data flow components such as derived column transformation, Lookups, in a way that can enhance the performance of the data import.
- If you cannot replace the UDF by SSIS components: If you are collecting data in high speed to a data lake (staging level) and then loading the data when needed, it is better to avoid using functions when importing data to staging table.
- If You need to guarantee a high speed when loading data from staging table, then use the function in the first data import phase.
- If the first data import phase (to staging table) and the second phase (from staging table) are not executed on the same machine, it could be better to execute functions on the more performant machine.
- If function contains some operations like lookups, try replacing them with joins.

...

## Update 1

After posting functions in your question, you can replace function 2 with a Derived Column Transformation in your SSIS package:

```
ISNULL([Column]) ? "" : REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Column],CHAR(10),""),CHAR(13),""),CHAR(09),""),CHAR(34),CHAR(39))
```

Also you can replace Function 1 with a Lookup Transformation in SSIS package or with a LEFT JOIN in SQL query.